# Powershell - How to replace dots on files exept the extension

Tags: powershell

I have a question about the replacement of dots on multiple files, i have the next code:

```
Dir | Rename-item -NewName{ $_.basename.replace(".","-") + $_.extension }
```

This code works, but i have folders with dots and the problem is when i run the code, the folders repeat the words after the point like a "file extension":

[image: i have a folder with dots, "carpeta.uno"]

like this:

[image: then i have a folder with "file extension (.uno)"]

How can i resolve this problem, i need just replace the dot on folder name with another word or space or everything i like and the files on the folder just replace before the extension.

thanks!

Comment: Filter by directory, or file first then rename?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the **`.BaseName`** ETS ([Extended Type System](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763)) property that PowerShell adds to [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances, i.e. ***directories***, by - unfortunate - design, unconditionally **reports the directory name *as-is***.

It is only for [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances, i.e. *files*, that `.BaseName` strips the extension, i.e., the last `.`-separated component.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can **work around the problem by calling the [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension) .NET method**, which does not make this distinction (similarly, the *type-native* `.Extension` property doesn't make this distinction either, so *it* can be used as-is).

```sh
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name).Replace('.', '-') + $_.Extension
}
```

---

<sup>[1] You can verify this as follows:

`(Get-TypeData System.IO.DirectoryInfo).Members.BaseName` vs.

`(Get-TypeData System.IO.FileInfo).Members.BaseName`</sup>